# Android allow layout cut off higher child

Tags: android, animation, crop

How i can insert an textview with height=100dp in parent layout with height=60 and display cropped textview?
I want to resize parent layout without resizing textview inside.

Comment: imho you can use margin with negative values

Answer (score 0):

Set a negative value to the `layout_marginTop` of your `TextView`, and after resizing the parent you should also set that `layout_marginTop` to zero. The layout is like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```